# Cordova to build Meteor apps for Cordova supported platforms

Tags: cordova, meteor

While [Cordova Command Line Interface page](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface) mentions deploying to those and various other platforms , [Meteor docs only mentions deploying to iOS and Android](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/buildingmobileapps).

Is it possible to deploy a Meteor project into other than iOS and Android mobile platforms, as well, like Windows Phone, Windows, Blackberry that mentioned in above Cordova Page?

Can I use Cordova CLI directly for building my Meteor app for the platforms Cordova supports instead of using Meteor command line integration with Cordova, `meteor build`? Can I do same thing in building for the iOS and Android, platforms Meteor supports building for?

**Briefly all above in a one-liner**:

**Can one directly use Cordova to build Meteor apps for Cordova supported platforms?**

Comment: `** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

2015-01-12 05:47:50.791 ios-sim[8809:119788] stderrPath: /Users/faruk/dev/todos_cordova/buildscordova/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log
2015-01-12 05:47:50.793 ios-sim[8809:119788] stdoutPath: /Users/faruk/dev/todos_cordova/buildscordova/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log
Session could not be started: Error Domain=DTiPhoneSimulatorErrorDomain Code=2 "Simulator session timed out." UserInfo=0x7f81a0e3fa50 {NSLocalizedDescription=Simulator session timed out.}`

Comment: `Error: /Users/faruk/dev/todos_cordova/buildscordova/platforms/ios/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)`

Comment: By the way I have built the meteor app with cordova. but I cannot use cordova for emulating it on iOS. In the simulator I have a cordova icon app with my apps name and it only shows device ready cordova page, while I have started server side meteor app alongside. The above is the Messages in Terminal after I have issues `cordova emulate iOS.`